# C# XML Linq on multiple tags of same name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have some projects in an XML file. eg. Multiple projects like the one below in the same file . I want to search all project entries where FluidTypes matches a particular string .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <Project ID="P-2014-000037">
    <Name>FDP001_Bakken</Name>
    <Manager>shell</Manager>
    <Area>NAM</Area>
    <Field>Bakken</Field>
    <Type>Time and Material External</Type>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <Value>3.5</Value>
    <Geomarket>NAM</Geomarket>
    <FormationTypes>Carbonate</FormationTypes>
    <FormationTypes>Coal</FormationTypes>
    <FormationTypes>Fractures</FormationTypes>
    <FormationTypes>Sandstone</FormationTypes>
    <FluidTypes>Gas Cond</FluidTypes>
    <FluidTypes>Heavy Oil</FluidTypes>
    <DriveMechanisms>Compaction</DriveMechanisms>
    <DriveMechanisms>Aquifer</DriveMechanisms>
    <EORProcesses>CO2</EORProcesses>
    <EORProcesses>CSS</EORProcesses>
  </Project>
</data>
```

I am using the follwing code to search for Geomarket matches :

```
   IEnumerable<XElement> values1 = from el1 in root.Elements("Project").
        Where(r => regEx1.IsMatch(r.Element("Geomarket").Value))
                                    select el1;
```

when I use same for Fluid type (which has multiple elements ):

```
       IEnumerable<XElement> values1 = from el1 in root.Elements("Project").
            Where(r => regEx1.IsMatch(r.Element("FluidTypes").Value))
                                        select el1;
```

It only checks for a match with the first element with name Fluid Types and not ALL fluid types elements . As a result only Gas Cond matches this project but Heavy Oil does not.

How to make  a query across all Fluid types search ?

Comment: Why you do not fit this: IEnumerable<XElement> values1 = root.Elements("Project").Elements("FluidTypes");

Comment: `I want to search all project entries where FluidTypes matches a particular string` For example?

Comment: For example : Search all projects where Fluid types = "Heavy Oil "

`  Regex regEx1 = new Regex("Heavy Oil", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: @Prasaanth Neelakandan. Use Regex after .Elements("FluidTypes")

Comment: That doesn't help my case because if I do root.Elements("Project").Elements("FluidTypes");   then only  Fluid Type Column is registered in my IEnumerable<XElement> values1 . I need the entire tuple i.e all columns in my IEnumerable<XElement> values1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) clause with a nested search:

```
        var projects = root
            .Elements("Project")
            .Where(el => el.Elements("FluidTypes").Where(el2 => regEx1.IsMatch(el2.Value)).Any());
```

This returns all elements named `"Project"` with at least one nested element named `"FluidTypes"` whose [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) matches your regular expression.

Or, use a nested [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
        var projects = root
            .Elements("Project")
            .Where(el => el.Elements("FluidTypes").Any(el2 => regEx1.IsMatch(el2.Value)));
```

Comment: Almost Identical with my question, I would go with this answer lol.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
IEnumerable<XElement> values1 = from el1 in root.Elements("Project").Elements("FluidTypes")
    .Where(r => regEx1.IsMatch(r.Value))
    Select el1;
```

Comment: Thanks . That doesn't help my case because if I do root.Elements("Project").Elements("FluidTypes"); then only Fluid Type Column is registered in my IEnumerable<XElement> values1 . I need the entire tuple i.e all columns in my IEnumerable<XElement> values1 .


`IEnumerable<XElement> values1 = from el1 in root.Elements("Project")
    .Where(r => regEx1.IsMatch(r.Value))
    Select el1;`

I tried this and it seemed to work in this case. However it looks for a match in all elements and not just Fluid Types.